# Python: How do I assign string values to numeric data?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Running the four commands results in below output, from a dataframe called `cancer`.

```
$ print("\n  target")
$ print(cancer.target)
$ print("\n  target_names")
$ print(cancer.target_names)

  target
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]

  target_names
['malignant' 'benign']
```

How would I be able to assign "malignant" to 0 and "benign" to 1, and vice versa?

Comment: how about [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) : `np.where(cancer.target,'benign','malignant')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map it by using a dictionary

```py
target=[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]

d={0:'malignant',1:'benign'}
target=[d[t] for t in target]
print(target)
['malignant', 'malignant', 'malignant', 'malignant', 'malignant', 'benign', 'benign', 'benign', 'malignant', 'benign', 'malignant', 'malignant', 'benign']
```

Answer (score 0):

What so you mean by assign?
Something like this?

```py
for i  in range(len(cancer)):
    if target[i]==0:
        target[i]=target_names[0]
    elif target[i]==1:
        target[i]=target_names[1]
```